# Christian scholars who have investigated and published on miracles?

Tags: reference-request, miracles

I'm mostly familiar with the work of Dr. Craig Keener ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig_S._Keener), [personal website](https://craigkeener.com/)), who has done extensive research on modern miracle accounts. See for example:

- Miracles: The Credibility of the New Testament Accounts ([amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0801039525))
- Miracles Today: The Supernatural Work of God in the Modern World ([amazon link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08MXZVXLW))
- Story Of Healings, Resurrections, and Miracles: With Dr. Keener ([YouTube video](https://youtu.be/EoJOmxcNL5I))

Are there or have there been other Christian scholars out there who have done similar research on modern miracles?

Comment: In the early church there were apostles, pastors, teachers, evangelists, overseers (bishops), elders and deacons. The 'scribes' were a function of the Jews. I cannot find any 'scholars' in Acts or the epistles. Do you mean University Professors who profess to be Christians ?

Comment: @NigelJ - according to https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/scholar: *a person who studies a subject in great detail, especially at a university*. Therefore being part of a university is recommended, but not mandatory as per the dictionary definition.

Comment: By that definition I would expect a 'Christianity Department' at a university to have a Professor with an appropriate title. Is that what you envisage ?

Comment: @NigelJ - that would be highly recommended, but not strictly necessary by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Lee Strobel](https://leestrobel.com/) is an investigative journalist and former legal editor for the Chicago Tribune who began as an atheist and, once converted to Christianity, began to report on such subjects. He has authored many titles including The Case for Christ, the Case for A Creator, and The Case for Miracles in 2018.

The Case for Miracles:

> Do miracles really exist?  New York Times bestselling author Lee Strobel trains his investigative sights on the hot-button issue of whether it’s credible to believe God intervenes supernaturally in people’s lives today. The book features the results of exclusive new scientific polling, and first-hand reports that show miracle accounts are much more common than people think. - From Lee Strobel.com

I have not read this particular book.